# Can't start broadcast reciever by Packet Manager

Tags: android

Can i use below way to start an broadcast receiver? Some one can get it run but i can't. I don't know why.

```
PackageManager pm  = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("brd2.demo", "brd2.demo.BroadcastReceiver");
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

this is my Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="brd2.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="brd2.demo.BroadcastReceiverDemo2Activity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver  android:name="brd2.demo.CallBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Pls, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are taking care to add appropriate actions in receivers.

And if your receiver class is 
extending broadcast receiver,Then system will take care to call your broadcast receiver.

You dont need to start broadcast receiver manually (Until and unless you are creating custom broadcasts).

In your case if `CallBroadcastReceiver` is extending `BroadcastReceiver` and if you have written appropriate logic in `onReceive`method,Then this class will automatically get called when you make new call or if phone rings.

Hope this help.